# FetchedResultsController blocks UI when its NSManagedObjectContext merging with another one in background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableViewController that conforms to NSFetchedResultsController protocol. 
After I downloading data from my server using a background thread to save in to Core Data I have to merge changes to my main thread NSManagedObject context used by an instance of NSFetchedResultsController in this tableView. Right after merging the UI is blocked(For a few seconds).(NSFetchedResultsController is updating). 
I am wondering what has caused this blocking?
Is there any way to bypass this blocking?

Because I think this NSFetchedResultsController updating is gonna update the UI so I assume It's not appropriate to place it in another thread.

Thank you guys.

Comment: do you have large data from server? may be this is the reason which take time to store and fetch by another context thats why UI gets blocked

Comment: I do not think that's case because I locally created equivalent of the data loaded from server and use foreground context to save it but now the NADetchedResultsController updates perfectly without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the point of UI being blocked is due to fetched controller react and updating the table view at each single change. Which is every time an NSManagedObject is being added to the store.

The quick solution, and probably the only one, is to download data in background, then resign the fetched controller from being delegate of UITableView controller, at this point you can do the update, and then restore the situation back to normal by reassigning the controller to be UITableView delegate, and then reissue the fetch.